# WebBrowser не загружает содержимое после Navigate

Tags: c#

Мне нужно произвести определённые действия на сайте (открыть страницу, ввести логин-пароль,перейти по ссылке в открывшейся странице, распарсить полученную страницу)
Решил использовать WebBrowser. Открыть страницу, залогиниться - получилось. Но по переходу по ссылке нужная мне страница уже не загружается в WebBrowser.Document, там лежит всё та же страница, открывшаяся после логина).
В этом и проблема, что я делаю не так, как получить уже конечную страницу. Код такой:

```
public static class Web
{
    static WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

    static int action_type;
    static void PageLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (action_type)
        {
            case 0:
                // вводим данные и логинимся
                wb.Document.GetElementById("login").InnerText = "123";
                wb.Document.GetElementById("passw").InnerText = "456";
                action_type = 1;
                foreach (HtmlElement hh in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                {
                    if (hh.GetAttribute("value") == "Войти")
                        hh.InvokeMember("click");
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                // переходим по ссылке с текстом АБВГД
                action_type = 2;
                foreach (HtmlElement link in wb.Document.Links)
                {
                    if (link.InnerText == "АБВГД")
                    {
                        string href = link.GetAttribute("href");
                        wb.Navigate(href);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                // смортим что тут есть
         // вот тут и проблема
                string s = ((WebBrowser)sender).DocumentText;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void test()
    {
        wb.AllowNavigation = true;
        wb.DocumentCompleted +=
           new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PageLoaded);            
        action_type = 0;
        wb.Navigate("сайт.html");

    }

}
```

Comment: А вы проверяете `wb.ReadyState`?

Comment: Я начал писать код именно так, но затем вычитал, что тот способ, что описан мною выше, то есть с использованием именно события, работает надёжнее.

Comment: Ну, вы по идее должны в событии проверять `ReadyState`. Может быть, вы реагируете на не то сообщение?